# forcing ViewWillAppear on selection of the same TabBarItem

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TabBarItem that when the user is already in it and clicks it again, I want the ViewWillAppear to be called even though the screen is already in place.
(this is a feed screen, and actually I will suffice in `UItableView` to scroll up)

I can do something in the didSelectViewController method but I'm not sure what is the correct way to tackle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the content of your `viewWillAppear` to a a third method. for example `fo` and then at both `viewWillAppear` and your `didSelectViewController` call the `fo` method.